# ANDROID STUDIO : Project Gradle Build Failed

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

[Click here to see screenshot]
1]Just installed android studio 4.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 ... And I tried to start a new project from examples that are present ... But immediately it load into the project page the build process failed with error 03 or so

Comment: Try creating a new project. Is the error still there?

Comment: have tried created a new project over and over again but i still got the error message... i will add screenshot of the error message to the question

Comment: can you upload  your error message